# Python Kafka client with client_rack attribute

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python, confluent-kafka-python

I have a requirement to set the client.rack attribute.

I am using kafka-python library version 2.02. (latest)
But it does not have client_rack attribute. But the libs support kafka 2.4.x which has client_rack property.

Error:

```
kafka.errors.KafkaConfigurationError: KafkaConfigurationError: Unrecognized configs: {'client_rack'}
```